# getting distinct rows for WHERE IN array having same values

Tags: mysql

For array = `[1,1,1,2]`, DB table has entry for `ids-1,2`.

The query -> "`SELECT * FROM table WHERE id in array"` returns only two rows.

Is there a way where it will return 4 rows instead?

Comment: There is only two rows in the table?

Comment: If there are only two rows on the table then that's all you will get from that query.

Answer (score 0):

You can build an in-line table with `UNION ALL`, then `INNER JOIN` your table to it:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (
   SELECT 1 AS v UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2
) AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 ON t1.v = t2.id
```